# DatabaseFactory not initialized when using sqflite in flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, dart, sqflite

I followed the following tutorial on the official site for sqflite: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite

But on this line

```
var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
```

I get the following error:

> Exception has occurred.
> StateError (Bad state: databaseFactory not initialized
> databaseFactory is only initialized when using sqflite. When using `sqflite_common_ffi`
> You must call `databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;` before using global openDatabase API
> )

These are my dependencies:

```
dependecies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  sqflite: ^2.2.8
  path: ^1.8.2
```

I tried to open the Database without getting a path from getDatabasePath():

```
await openDatabase('demo.db', version: 1,...
```

But this throws the same error on openDatabase.

As I am not using sqflite_common_ffi I do not know what to do and would appreciate your help.

**Edit:**
I now also tried to use the complete example on the end of the page [docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite). I think it is some kind of configuration error, because the same project works on another machine of mine.

Comment: Any chance you are using a platform that requires sqflite_common_ffi? Linux/Windows/DartVM require it, according to sqflite readme.

Answer (score 5):

```
dependencies:
   sqflite_common_ffi: any

//in main.dart write this:
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';
Future main() async {

// Initialize FFI
sqfliteFfiInit();


 databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
 runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First add the dependency:

dependencies:
sqflite_common_ffi:
On iOS, Android and MacOS, add

dependencies:
sqlite3_flutter_libs:

### try the following code

---

```
import 'package:sqflite_common_ffi/sqflite_ffi.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

Future main() async {
  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux) {
    // Initialize FFI
    sqfliteFfiInit();
  }
  // Change the default factory. On iOS/Android, if not using `sqlite_flutter_lib` you can forget
  // this step, it will use the sqlite version available on the system.
  databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfi;
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something I usually did is this way, hope this snap shot help you

```dart
  /// singleton pattern
  AppDataBase._internal() {
    // if (_database == null) database;
  }
  static final AppDataBase instance = AppDataBase._internal();

  /// sqflite datbase instance
  static Database? _database;

  /// gets database instance
  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database != null) return _database!;
    _database = await _initDB();
    return _database!;
  }

  /// initialize the database
  Future<Database> _initDB() async {
    print('createing databse');
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, 'taskino.db');
    print('path is $path');
    return await openDatabase(path,
        version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate, onConfigure: _onConfigure);
  }
```

then from the main I call my init to create db  like this

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  await WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AppDataBase.instance.initDb();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I hope this helps you to could initialize your db

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately it does not help. I now also tried to use the complete example on the end of the page https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/persistence/sqlite.
I think it is some kind of configuration error, because the same project works on another machine of mine.

Comment: could you please share more code?

Answer (score 0):

i was getting the same error and it sqflite does not supports web. For this purpose you have to use another package sqflite_common_ffi_web with sqf lite.

I got rid of this error by adding adding this check on web:

```
if (kIsWeb) {
 // Change default factory on the web
 databaseFactory = databaseFactoryFfiWeb;
 path = 'my_web_web.db';
}
```

Add this code just befor your opedDatabase() method

Comment: complementing your good anwser for those who are using sqflite for webapp with flutter the package https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite_common_ffi_web do the magic to make this works, so we should keep your code in the singleton creation and import this lib and run it's setup command line